# Remove space at the beginning of a row of a table

Tags: tables

[image]

Can someone please help me with removing the space at the beginning of each row in the table? I have tried everything: \arraystretch, \tablerowsep, \vspace{}. Nothing has worked so far. 
Here is a part of the beginning of the code:

```
    \documentclass[8pt]{article}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{easytable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow,hhline,graphicx,array}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

%\DeclareMathSizes{8}{16}{16}{8}

\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\g}{\mathbf{g}}
\newcommand{\h}{\mathbf{h}}
\newcommand{\0}{\mathbf{0}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{landscape}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.7em}| p{0.7em}|p{20em}|p{21em}|p{21em}|}
    \cmidrule{3-5}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    &       
    & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Unconstrained} \\ $\underset{\x\in\mathbb{R}^n}    
{\mathrm{minimize}}\ f(\x)$}
&
\makecell{\textbf{Constrained: Reduced Form} \\                     
$\underset{\x\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\mathrm{minimize}}\ f(\x)$ \\
$\mathrm{subject\ to\ } \h(\x)=\0 $} 
& 
\makecell{\textbf{Constrained: Lagrangian Form} \\ 
$\underset{\x\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\mathrm{minimize}}\ f(\x)$ \\
$\mathrm{subject\ to\ } \h(\x)=\0,\g(\x)\leq\0$ }
   \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{Local Optimality 
Conditions}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.7em}|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\ First 
Order Necessary\ }} 
& 
At a local minimizer, the gradient of the objective function must be zero 
\[
\nabla f(\x_\dagger)=\0
\]
&       
At a local minimizer, the reduced gradient must be zero if $\partial     
h/\partial s$ is invertible.
\[
\nabla_d f_R (x_{\dagger})=0
\]
\[
h(x_{\dagger})=0
\]
\[
\text{where } x= \begin{bmatrix}
d\\s
\end{bmatrix}
,\nabla_d f_R (x_{\dagger})=\frac{\partial f}{\partial d}-\frac{\partial f}    
{\partial s} \bigg( \frac{\partial h}{\partial s} \bigg )^{-1}\frac{\partial 
h}{\partial d}
\]
&  
At a local minimizer, the KKT conditions must be satisfied if the point is     
regular (i.e.: if the linear independence constraint qualification (LICQ) is 
satisfied: if $\nabla h_{\dagger}(x_{*})$ has independent rows).
\[
\nabla _x L(x_{\dagger})=0  
\]
\[
h(x_{\dagger})=0,g(x_{\dagger})≤0
\]
\[
\mu_{\dagger}^⊤ g(x_{\dagger})=0
\]
\[
\mu_{\dagger}≥0
\]
\[
\text{where } L(x_{\dagger})=f(x_{\dagger})+\lambda^⊤ h(x_{\dagger})+μ^⊤     
g(x_{\dagger})
\]
\\
\cmidrule{2-5}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
& 
\multicolumn{1}{p{0.7em}|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\ Second Order 
 Sufficiency\ }} 
&  
If the Hessian of the objective function is positive definite at a point 
where the gradient is zero, the point is a local minimum.
\[
\partial x^T\nabla^2f(x_{*})\partial x>0
\]
\[
\forall \partial x \neq 0
\]
A Hessian matrix is positive definite if all of its eigenvalues are 
positive.
&    
If the reduced Hessian is positive definite at a point where the reduced 
gradient is zero, the point is a local minimum.
\[
\partial d^⊤ \nabla_d^2 f_R (x_{*})\partial d>0, \forall \partial d \neq 0
\]
\[
\text{where }\nabla_d^2 f_R (x_{*})=A \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}     
A^{T}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial s} \frac{\partial ^2 s}{\partial d^2}
\]
\[
A=
\bigg[
I \hspace{2mm}\bigg({\frac{\partial s}{\partial d}\bigg)}^T
\bigg]
,  \frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial d^2} =-\bigg(\frac{\partial h}{\partial 
s}\bigg)^{-1} A \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2} A^{T}
\]
&  
If the Hessian of the Lagrangian is positive definite on the subspace      
tangent to the active constraints at a KKT point, the point is a local 
minimum.
\[
\partial x^T\nabla^2_x L(x_{*})\partial x>0
\]
\[
\forall \partial x \neq 0: \nabla_x h_{\dagger}(x_{*})\partial x = 0
\]
\[
\text{where }h_{\dagger}(x_{*}) = [h(x_{*})^T, g_j(x_{*})\forall 
 j:\mu_j>0]^T
\]
 A Hessian matrix is positive definite on the subspace tangent to the active     
 constraints if the last n-m leading principle minors of the bordered 
 Hessian $\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & \nabla h\\ \nabla h^T & \nabla^2_x L
 \end{bmatrix}$have sign $(-1)^m$, where m is the number of active 
 constraints.


\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.4em}|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{\ Global 
 Optimality Conditions}\ }} 
&
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.4em}|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{\ Convexity}\ 
}} 
&       
    \begin{itemize}
    \item For convex functions, if a point is a local minimum it is also the 
    global minimum and a local minimizer is also a global minimizer (not 
    necessarily the only one).
    \item If the objective function is nonconvex, it may or may not have multiple local minima.
    \item A convex function* is a function whose Hessian is positive semidefinite for all x.
    \item A Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite if all of its eigenvalues are nonnegative.
\end{itemize}
& 

 \multicolumn{1}{c}{}

&
\begin{itemize}
    \item A convex optimization problem is a problem in negative null form where f(x) and g(x) are each convex functions and h(x) are affine functions.
    \item For convex optimization problems, a local minimum is also the global minimum, and a local minimizer is also a global minimizer (not necessarily the only one).
    \item A nonconvex optimization problem may or may not have multiple 
    local minima and/or disconnected feasible regions.
 \end{itemize} 
 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please complete your code such that it starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors?

Comment: Using `\rotatebox[origin=r]{...}` instead of `c` should get you a little further. But without a complete MWE it's impossible to give more help.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. I just coped the entire code. I hope that gives some insights.

Comment: Well, there is an `\end{document}` missing, isn't it? And after I add this and compile with `xelatex` or `\lualatex` there is no issue. Which compiler do you use? (I can't compile with `pdflatex` since you include some special characters.)

Comment: Hi I put the \end{document} back in. I had forgotten to copy that. I am working on sharelatex, which uses the default pdflatex. I have not had any issues with compiling.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you very much for your help. Can you please tell me the difference between origin=r and origin = c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer. All I did is to convert your code fragments into an MWE. Interestingly, the issue does not arise there. So it must come from some package that you load or something else that is not shown in your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,makecell,multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\newcommand{\h}{\ensuremath{h}}
\newcommand{\g}{\ensuremath{g}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0ex}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0ex}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{landscape}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.7em}| p{0.7em}|p{20em}|p{21em}|p{21em}|}
    \cmidrule{3-5}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    &       
    & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Unconstrained} \\ $\underset{\x\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\mathrm{minimize}}\ f(\x)$}
    &
    \makecell{\textbf{Constrained: Reduced Form} \\ $\underset{\x\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\mathrm{minimize}}\ f(\x)$ \\
    $\mathrm{subject\ to\ } \h(\x)=0 $} 
    & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Constrained: Lagrangian Form} \\ $\underset{\x\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\mathrm{minimize}}\ f(\x)$ \\
    $\mathrm{subject\ to\ } \h(\x)=0,\g(\x)\leq 0$ }
       \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{Local Optimality Conditions}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.7em}|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\ First Order Necessary\ }} 
    & 
    At a local minimizer, the gradient of the objective function must be zero 
    \[
    \nabla f(\x_\dagger)=0
    \]
    &       
    At a local minimizer, the reduced gradient must be zero if $\partial h/\partial s$ is invertible.
\end{tabular}   
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I guess that unless you are super lucky the only way to proceed is that you provide a complete MWE, not just fragments.

**ADDENDUM**: I could not reproduce the error with your full code (amended by an `\end{document}` when compiled with `xelatex` or `lualatex` on my TeXLive 2018 distribution. I am also surprised that `\0` works. Here is a code in which I implemented @Mike's suggestion along with another minor change.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{easytable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}    
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow,hhline,graphicx,array}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

%\DeclareMathSizes{8}{16}{16}{8}

\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\g}{\mathbf{g}}
\newcommand{\h}{\mathbf{h}}
\newcommand{\0}{\mathbf{0}} %<- that's not a good idea
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{landscape}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.7em}| p{0.7em}|p{20em}|p{21em}|p{21em}|}
    \cmidrule{3-5}    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    &       
    & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Unconstrained} \\ $\underset{\x\in\mathbb{R}^n}    
{\mathrm{minimize}}\ f(\x)$}
&
\makecell{\textbf{Constrained: Reduced Form} \\                     
$\underset{\x\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\mathrm{minimize}}\ f(\x)$ \\
$\mathrm{subject\ to\ } \h(\x)=\0 $} 
& 
\makecell{\textbf{Constrained: Lagrangian Form} \\ 
$\underset{\x\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\mathrm{minimize}}\ f(\x)$ \\
$\mathrm{subject\ to\ } \h(\x)=\0,\g(\x)\leq\0$ }
   \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\makecell{Local Optimality 
Conditions~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.7em}|}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\ First 
Order Necessary\ }} 
& 
At a local minimizer, the gradient of the objective function must be zero 
\[
\nabla f(\x_\dagger)=\0
\]
&       
At a local minimizer, the reduced gradient must be zero if $\partial     
h/\partial s$ is invertible.
\[
\nabla_d f_R (x_{\dagger})=0
\]
\[
h(x_{\dagger})=0
\]
\[
\text{where } x= \begin{bmatrix}
d\\s
\end{bmatrix}
,\nabla_d f_R (x_{\dagger})=\frac{\partial f}{\partial d}-\frac{\partial f}    
{\partial s} \bigg( \frac{\partial h}{\partial s} \bigg )^{-1}\frac{\partial 
h}{\partial d}
\]
&  
At a local minimizer, the KKT conditions must be satisfied if the point is     
regular (i.e.: if the linear independence constraint qualification (LICQ) is 
satisfied: if $\nabla h_{\dagger}(x_{*})$ has independent rows).
\[
\nabla _x L(x_{\dagger})=0  
\]
\[
h(x_{\dagger})=0,g(x_{\dagger})≤0
\]
\[
\mu_{\dagger}^⊤ g(x_{\dagger})=0
\]
\[
\mu_{\dagger}≥0
\]
\[
\text{where } L(x_{\dagger})=f(x_{\dagger})+\lambda^⊤ h(x_{\dagger})+μ^⊤     
g(x_{\dagger})
\]
\\
\cmidrule{2-5}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} 
& 
\multicolumn{1}{p{0.7em}|}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\ Second Order 
 Sufficiency\ }} 
&  
If the Hessian of the objective function is positive definite at a point 
where the gradient is zero, the point is a local minimum.
\[
\partial x^T\nabla^2f(x_{*})\partial x>0
\]
\[
\forall \partial x \neq 0
\]
A Hessian matrix is positive definite if all of its eigenvalues are 
positive.
&    
If the reduced Hessian is positive definite at a point where the reduced 
gradient is zero, the point is a local minimum.
\[
\partial d^⊤ \nabla_d^2 f_R (x_{*})\partial d>0, \forall \partial d \neq 0
\]
\[
\text{where }\nabla_d^2 f_R (x_{*})=A \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}     
A^{T}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial s} \frac{\partial ^2 s}{\partial d^2}
\]
\[
A=
\bigg[
I \hspace{2mm}\bigg({\frac{\partial s}{\partial d}\bigg)}^T
\bigg]
,  \frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial d^2} =-\bigg(\frac{\partial h}{\partial 
s}\bigg)^{-1} A \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2} A^{T}
\]
&  
If the Hessian of the Lagrangian is positive definite on the subspace      
tangent to the active constraints at a KKT point, the point is a local 
minimum.
\[
\partial x^T\nabla^2_x L(x_{*})\partial x>0
\]
\[
\forall \partial x \neq 0: \nabla_x h_{\dagger}(x_{*})\partial x = 0
\]
\[
\text{where }h_{\dagger}(x_{*}) = [h(x_{*})^T, g_j(x_{*})\forall 
 j:\mu_j>0]^T
\]
 A Hessian matrix is positive definite on the subspace tangent to the active     
 constraints if the last n-m leading principle minors of the bordered 
 Hessian $\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & \nabla h\\ \nabla h^T & \nabla^2_x L
 \end{bmatrix}$have sign $(-1)^m$, where m is the number of active 
 constraints.


\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.4em}|}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\makecell{\ Global 
 Optimality Conditions}\ }} 
&
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.4em}|}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\makecell{\ Convexity}\ 
}} 
&       
    \begin{itemize}
    \item For convex functions, if a point is a local minimum it is also the 
    global minimum and a local minimizer is also a global minimizer (not 
    necessarily the only one).
    \item If the objective function is nonconvex, it may or may not have multiple local minima.
    \item A convex function* is a function whose Hessian is positive semidefinite for all x.
    \item A Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite if all of its eigenvalues are nonnegative.
\end{itemize}
& 

 \multicolumn{1}{c}{}

&
\begin{itemize}
    \item A convex optimization problem is a problem in negative null form where f(x) and g(x) are each convex functions and h(x) are affine functions.
    \item For convex optimization problems, a local minimum is also the global minimum, and a local minimizer is also a global minimizer (not necessarily the only one).
    \item A nonconvex optimization problem may or may not have multiple 
    local minima and/or disconnected feasible regions.
 \end{itemize} 
 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

[image]

So from my point of view the issue cannot be reproduced. Does it really show up when you compile this very code on your machine?

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. I have copied the entire code now. I hope that gives some insights.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much. When I copied your code, it works! Can you please tell me what is the other minor change you made? Also while we are at it, can you please tell me how I can move the bullet points in the last row second column to the left edge and not leave out so much white space? I combined two columns but I am not able to get the text to spread to both the columns. It remains on either the left or right column, even after being combined. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Also there is some space left at the end of the column. Can you please tell me how to get rid of that? I am just trying to fit in a lot of data. So it would be really nice if I could know of some way. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Cat What I remember is that I put all the `~~~~~` signs to center `Local Optimality Conditions`. I also made the column wider, but both of my modifications are suboptimal. My post was merely to say that I cannot reproduce the issue you reported. Actually it would be great if you could find out what caused them, i.e. create an MWE that has these issues because you may have discovered something serious. All other things would probably amount to completely redesigning the table. I'd like to ask you to ask a separate question for this, you might get helped by some table experts.

Comment: So I asked a separate question on this. Thanks for all your help. Can you please tell me the difference between origin=r and origin = c?

Comment: The difference between `\rotate[origin=c]` and `\rotate[origin=r]` is that in the first case the object gets rotated about its `c`enter  and in the second case it gets rotated about its `r`ightmost point, i.e. the point at the middle of the right edge of its bounding box. Likewise for `l`, for more details type `texdoc graphicx`. (This is a weird world in which a marmot answers questions by a cat. ;-)

Comment: Yeah a weird world where animals talk like humans! I should change my display picture to that of a cat. Thanks for all your help again!